# Retrieve Account Number using account GUID in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, guid

I'm new to LINQ so please apology if I ask wrong question. I want to retrieve account number in Dynamics CRM using account GUID and LINQ. But unable to find. I've following snippet but gives me exception that **specified cast is not valid**

```
 accountID = (Guid)contact["parentcustomerid"];
 var account = from a in context.CreateQuery("account")
 where a.GetAttributeValue<Guid?>("accountid") == accountID
 select new {accountNumber = a["accountnumber"] };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `accountID` ? `Guid` or `Nullable<Guid>`

try below snippet:

```
accountID = (Guid)contact["parentcustomerid"];
var account = from a in context.CreateQuery("account")
where a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid") == accountID
select new {accountNumber = a.GetAttributeValue<int>("accountnumber") };
```

you can use `Query Expression`. It is very easy to use:

```
QueryExpression queryExpression = new QueryExpression("account");
queryExpression.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("accountnumber");
queryExpression.Criteria.AddCondition("accountid", ConditionOperator.Equal, accountID);
```

Or

```
_service.Retrieve("account", accountID, new ColumnSet("accountnumber"));
```

Comment: service.retrieve returns "Microsoft.Xrm.SDK.Entity" and when I debug it shows only id in the attributes. can you help in this

Comment: @MohsinAli have you specified `new ColumnSet("accountnumber")`

Comment: yes,here it is, Entity account = service.Retrieve(account.LogicalName, accountID, new ColumnSet("accountnumber"));

Comment: @MohsinAli If the `accountnumber` is null, then it will not be in attributes.
i am sure it is null.

Comment: I even try this : ColumnSet col1 = new ColumnSet();
                    col1.Columns.Add("accountnumber");
but no luck

Comment: @MohsinAli Glad it helped,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following:

```
var accountID = contact.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("parentcustomerid").Id;

var accountnumber = (from a in context.CreateQuery("account")
 where a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid") == accountID
 select a.GetAttributeValue<string>("accountnumber")).FirstOrDefault();
```